# WD my book live сменил DHCP на статический IP. Не находит WD!

Tags: debian, ip, nas

Что делать?
Уже и подключал WD напрямую к компу через ethernet кабель, там пробовал зайти через станый (локальный 192.168.0.2 IP) и через новый. Написал им в техподдержку, они еще не ответили. В доках написано, что кнопку сброса 4 сек. зажать и сбросятся пароли, а данные останутся. Но там ОООчень ценные данные и если хоть малейшая вероятность их удаления есть, то лучше кнопку сброса не нажимать.

---

из комментария:

На компе стоит автоматически принимать адрес - (далее идет на роутер), и на роутере уже стоит статический 172.82.2.3 (от туда же я и поставил на NAS) тот же адрес 172.82.2.3 и туже маску. P.S: тоже подозреваю, что конфликт IP, т.к. по 172.82.2.3 - открывается роутер, а по 172.82.2.3/UI ничего не открывается. (Хотя раньше это был адрес WD - 192.168.0.2/UI).

Comment: а на компьютере адрес меняете, чтобы соответствовал испытуемому. Например у WD 192.168.0.2 - на компе прописать например 192.168.0.3. Отключить компьютер и WD от других сетевых устройств на всякий случай, чтобы наверняка не возникал конфликт адресов.

Comment: На компе стоит автоматически принимать адрес - (далее идет на роутер), и на роутере уже стоит статический 172.82.2.3 (от туда же я и поставил на NAS) тот же адрес 172.82.2.3 и туже маску.
P.S: тоже подозреваю, что конфликт IP, т.к. по 172.82.2.3 - открывается роутер, а по 172.82.2.3/UI ничего не открывается. (Хотя раньше это был адрес WD - 192.168.0.2/UI).

Comment: у каждого устройства должен быть свой адрес, отличный от других. Выход: установить на компе статику 172.82.2.4 и туже маску, Отключить от роутера, подключить к WD, исправить WD, вернуть компу автомат. адрес, подключить всё у роутеру

Comment: Спасибо огромное banme!!! Все исправил, тем способом что ты написал.
Обратился в сетевую техподдержку, они сначала посоветовали сбросить настройки =\, а после изменить настройки NAS (подключить nas патч-кордом к пк).

Answer (score 1):

из комментария:

---

у каждого устройства должен быть свой адрес, отличный от других. Выход: установить на компе статику 172.82.2.4 и туже маску, Отключить от роутера, подключить к WD, исправить WD, вернуть компу автомат. адрес, подключить всё у роутеру.

Comment: примерно так и сделал месяцев 5-6 назад!